# How to change taskbar icon in NW.js?

Tags: icons, taskbar, nwjs

I would like to setup custom taskbar icon, but config not working. I treid to use `PNG` and `ICO` files, but it makes no sense.

I've searched a lot and found [that](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5006) and [that](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5822), but it doesn't help with my issue.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
  "name": "nwjsapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.18",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.13",
    "async-file-dl": "^0.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "child-process": "^1.0.2",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "download-file-with-progressbar": "^1.2.3",
    "filenamify": "^4.1.0",
    "is-admin": "^3.0.0",
    "node-machine-id": "^1.1.12",
    "nw-autoupdater": "^1.1.10",
    "nw-react-scripts": "2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "runas": "^3.1.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "spawn-as-admin": "^0.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "trim-character": "^2.0.1",
    "walk-promise": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nw-react-scripts start",
    "build": "nw-react-scripts build",
    "test": "nw-react-scripts test",
    "eject": "nw-react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "nw-react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "main": "index.html",
  "nwBuilder": {
    "//": "https://github.com/nwjs-community/nw-builder",
    "platforms": [
      "win64"
    ],
    "version": "latest",
    "flavor": "normal",
    "buildDir": "./build",
    "cacheDir": "./cache",
    "macIcns": "./src/logo.icns"
  },
  "window": {
    "resizable": false,
    "toolbar": false,
    "frame": false,
    "width": 391,
    "height": 444,
    "position": "center",
    "icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

I would like to change this icon to custom:

[image: Default taskbar Icon]

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the right place ***package.json:window:icon***

The problem is the path where your icon.png is located. Change to something like *"build/icon.png"* where *build* is the folder of your build target.